# Getting NSURLErrorUnsupportedURL (error code -1002) when loading a url in WebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

When a cell is selected in my `UITableView`, I set `self.itemURL` to that cell's respective URL, then segue to `WebViewController` and load up that URL.

Here's the logic that happens when a cell is tapped:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (_matchCenterDone == YES) {
        self.itemURL = _matchCenterArray[indexPath.section][@"Top 3"][indexPath.row+1][@"Item URL"];
        NSLog(@"The URL IS:'%@", self.itemURL);
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"WebViewSegue" sender:self];
    }
}
```

The NSLog prints out `The URL IS:'http://www.ebay.com/itm/NEW-Sony-XPERIA-Z3-Compact-D5803-FACTORY-UNLOCKED-/131554310432?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0`, which tells me that `self.itemURL` does in fact exist, and is a properly formatted URL.

Before I segue to `WebViewController`, I do this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"WebViewS egue"]){
        // Opens item in browser
        WebViewController *controller = (WebViewController *) segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.itemURL = self.itemURL;
    }
}
```

Here's what `WebViewController`s `viewDidLoad` function looks like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"The url in webview is: '%@'", self.itemURL);

    // Initialize UIWebView
    self.myWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, self.view.frame.size.width,
                                                                 self.view.frame.size.height)];;
    self.myWebView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.myWebView];


    // set the url
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.itemURL];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    // make url request
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil) {
             [self.myWebView loadRequest:request];
             [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
         }
         else if (error != nil) NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
     }];

    [self.myWebView setScalesPageToFit:YES]; 
}
```

The NSLog above logs out `The url in webview is: '(null)'` and the console logs out an error stating `Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo=0x7fcbfa5e7f10 {NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fcbfa64bec0 "unsupported URL"}`

What's happening between my initial view controller and `WebViewController` that's causing `self.itemURL` become null, and therefore unable to load the url?

Comment: You have a typo in `WebViewController` ... `WebViewS egue`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a space in your segue identifier string in your `prepareForSegue:` method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"WebViewS egue"]){
                                                 // ^ space here
        // Opens item in browser
        WebViewController *controller = (WebViewController *) segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.itemURL = self.itemURL;
    }
}
```

You *are* segueing to an instance of `WebViewController`, but its `itemURL` property is not being set because the code in that if statement is not being executed.

Take out the space and it should work.